# SVG: orbit items around point and keep them oriented vertically

Tags: animation, svg, rotation

I have a series of logos I am trying to rotate in a circle around a center point. Like a ferris wheel.

I can do the rotation fine, but I am trying to have the logos (i.e. the ferris wheel cabins) stay right-side up as the circle goes around.

Is there any way to do this in SVG?

Comment: Let's see what you have now and we can adjust it.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034185/how-to-move-element-arround-a-circle/44035864#44035864) shows the principle: rotate the logo backwards around its own centre while it rotates forward around the animation center.